# how to use st_intersection() with re-projection in POSTGIS?

Tags: postgresql, gis, polygon, postgis, shapefile

This is a shipping route from 'portland to busan' and I want to check the route against land_polygons like how much distance is traveled by a route through land.And the problem is while checking the land intersection it  consider as if the route is passing through North America,Europe etc. though it is not passing through any land region in real.

[image: shipping route from portland to busan]

```
    SELECT sum(ST_Length(ST_Intersection(route::geography,polygon))) as intersection
FROM land_polygons l,
    routes t
where t.route_id = ? and 
      ST_intersects(route::geometry,geom);
```

postgis version:

> POSTGIS="2.1.7 r13414" GEOS="3.4.2-CAPI-1.8.2 r3921" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0,
>   6 March 2012" GDAL="GDAL 1.10.1, released 2013/08/26" LIBXML="2.9.1"
>   LIBJSON="UNKNOWN" TOPOLOGY RASTER

Answer (score 0):

How is the route being constructed? It looks like it's being constructed until the date-line, and then from that as a straight line to the "next" date-line, to destination.

You should be constructing these routes as great circle distances, between the sea points.

Interesting blogs/answers:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109562/does-postgis-have-a-vincenty-distance-calculation
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84443/what-is-this-postgis-query-doing-to-show-great-circle-connections
http://anitagraser.com/2011/08/20/visualizing-global-connections/

The key to all of these examples is the use of ST_Segmentize, that will create many vertices along a projected line, virtually "bending" the line.

After the route construction problem is handled (you are indeed connection two points that are not on the route, going over land), use the spheroid distance functions to get an accurate measure.